# UILabel runs past size of screen

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel

My `UILabel` text goes offscreen, instead of cutting off before it runs off screen.

Can anyone help with this?  Thanks

`WebListCell.m`

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
self.headlineLabel.frame = CGRectMake(15, 15, 200, 25);
[self.headlineLabel setNumberOfLines:1];
[self.headlineLabel sizeToFit];
}
```

Update:
I ended up using Storyboards for this and pinning the label to each side with the Pin menu.  So use the Pin menu if you'd like to do this on Storyboard.
[image]

Or use code per accepted answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is you are calling `sizeToFit` method which automatically resizes the frame of your label to fit the text.

Try by not calling that method.